# How to supress the progress bar in an R script on linux machine

Tags: r, linux, progress-bar

How can I supress the progress bar that shows up in the R console?

Im running a self written R function on a VM that runs on ubuntu. When my script does it's thing (which takes a while) the console output looks like this:

```
> a = my_function("name_of_a_directory")
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
```

[screenshot of console output in R via vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPBhH.png)

How can I get rid of it, since it clutters my console especially since it repeats if my function does it's thing for multiple files, so that it looks like this:

```
> a = my_function("name_of_a_directory")
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
|--------------------------------------------------|
|==================================================|
```

If I run my script locally on a windows machine the progress bar does not show up so I guess it has something to do with that.

EDIT: thanks to @r2evans comment the issue was fixed. In `fread`s documentation you find `showProgress     TRUE displays progress on the console if the ETA is greater than 3 seconds. It is produced in fread's C code where the very nice (but R level) txtProgressBar and tkProgressBar are not easily available.`

Comment: This isn't an "R" thing by itself, it's likely related to something in your function. Common progress bars (though not an exhaustive list) include `data.table::fread` and many functions in the tidyverse. There's likely nothing we can really do to truly remove it without knowing what `my_function` looks like. (There may be a way to capture it, not sure, try `capture.output` or `suppressMessages`, but I don't have high confidence that either will work ... and they are admittedly addressing a symptom where a better solution likely exists, and I don't know of unintended side-effects.)

Comment: Thank you very much. My sub functions use ```fread``` and ```read_excel```. I can look into that later. This gives me a good starting point, since my thinking was it must have something todo with the console itself.

Comment: `?fread` has an argument `showProgress=`, and `?read_excel` has `progress=`.

Comment: Thank you @r2evans, the issue was resolved by setting ```showProgress = FALSE```.